# Why use $or instead of $and?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning how to use Mongo at the moment, and was wondering about the reasoning under the syntax.

In a database of actors, to search for all male actors that are ALSO English, the query is:

```
db.actors.find({gender: 'm', $or: [{nationality: 'english'}]});
```

Forgive my naiveté, but why wouldn't it make more sense to use "and" as follows?

```
db.actors.find({gender: 'm', $and: [{nationality: 'english'}]});
```

There must be reasoning for this that I'm missing (or I'm having a really bad day).  What is it?

Comment: where is the tutorial where you saw this query?

Comment: never mind, found it. tutsplus - there are *lots* of incorrect things there, I wouldn't use those - comments do point out some of the mistakes, but the original article was never corrected.

Comment: Yep, it was one of those ones - super annoying.  Kind of sucky to have bad information lodging in your head when you're early on in the learning process.  Another win for Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the and/or in the wrong place.

It is *not*  (Male OR english), it is (Male AND (English OR no other options)).

You only need to use $or if you have more than one condition in that second list.

Your query can be more easily written as:

```
  { gender: 'M', nationality: 'English' }
```

There is always an implicit AND between all top-level conditions.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  I'm going to blame it on a fairly misleading tutorial I'm following.  :)

Answer (score 0):

`$and` and `$or` aren't infix operators; they take an array of arguments. In your case, your two queries are equivalent, because you're passing in a single-element array: (*x* OR *y*) differs from (*x* AND *y*), but when you've only got one element, *x* is the same as *x* whether it's theoretically "OR" or "AND".

I guess you want:

```
db.actors.find({gender: 'm', nationality: 'english'});
```